# Summing up values from a user-defined range

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a spreadsheet from January 1 to present. and I needed to sum up the value parallel corresponding from the range which the user defines.

For example:

- in Column A are the dates January 1 - Present
- in Column B are the income (Figures) to present
- in Column D3 is which the user will input first date
- in Column D4 is which the user will input the second date
- and finally in F3 the total income in which ever the user input from the range

Comment: It'd be helpful if you could provide a screenshot or some real example data.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to look into using a SUMIFS formula in cell **F3** - something like this:

```
=SUMIFS(Column B, Column A, ">="&D3, Column A "<="&D4)
```